# Are there relations between two project files whose parent directories are a pair of parent and child?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2015, suppose that the parent directories of the project files A and B are dirA and dirB.

If dirA is a parent directory of dirB, is there some relation between the project files A and B, and relation between the projects they represent? For example, if I have opened the project file A in Visual Studio IDE, and want to open project file B, do I need to open project file B again or is it not necessary?

The confusion I have comes from not understanding how Visual Studio organizes the files and directories of a project.

Thanks.

Comment: Create a solution and then add an additional project to that solution. Default organization will be obvious. Essentially projects A and B are independant of there relative location (assuming you don't use same location with conflicting files).

Answer (score 1):

Directory structure means nothing to VS.
The most flexible system is usually to put all your project folders under the same solution root directory. In your solution (.sln) you add any existing projects you are interested in and create any required references between the projects.

If you want to create structure in VS it is best to use solution folders (right click Solution in explorer pane) and drag the projects into the solution folders.

Solution folders are not real folders. They only exist in the .sln file.

The reason that I recommend this approach is that it's trivial to reorganize solution folders but painful to restructure the directory hierarchy whenever you think of a new organization. This is because moving projects between solution folders doesn't break any links between projects as they are stored as relative path hints in the project files.

Answer (score 1):

Projects are independent. So how they're presented in file system doesn't matter.

But you can make them related (=grouped) to one solution. This's only how you can organize them logically. However, this still doesn't make any implicit relationship between them from the code point of view.

But projects in the same solution can be easily referenced to each other which defines explicit relation (as a tree hierarchy), i.e. projA can be dependant on projB. And therefore this hierarchical tree (or any of its subtree) can be seamlessly compiled as whole (one by one in particular order from leaves to root).